# Excel: averageif function for more than one cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data like this:

```
   A  B  C  D  E
1  6  7  8  9  1
2  1  2  3  4  5
3  N2 N4 N3 N5 N1
```

All the values are associated with numbers (`N1, N2 ...`). I know how to get one value by number using `SUMIF`:

```
=SUMIF($A$3:$E$3; "N1"; $A$2:$E$2) ' will get "5"
```

But I have another task: I need to get average of last `m` values before value founded with `SUMIF` (or `AVERAGEIF`).
For example for `m=3`, `N = N1` and `row = 2`: we'll find number "5" and get average of last three values in row before `N1`: `(5 + 4 + 3) / 3 = 4`
How could I do it correctly?

Comment: AVERAGEIF = SUMIF / COUNTIF

Comment: In that case, are you sure that N1 occurs only once in the row that need to checked for condition?  SUMIF will return the sum of all values where N is found.  If more than 1, N is found in this case, how the average will be dealt?  please clarify?

Comment: What happens if N=N2 in your case

Comment: @AnilGoyal, in `row = 3` all values (numbers) are unique

Comment: @JvdV this won't happen in task conditions

Comment: Does that mean, it'll never be a situation when there are less than m values to find and average?

Answer (score 2):

In case you do not have Excel O365, you could use:

[image]

Formula in `L2`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INDEX(A1:E2,I3,ROW(INDEX(A:A,MAX(MATCH(I2,A3:E3,0)-I1+1,1)):INDEX(A:A,MATCH(I2,A3:E3,0)))))/I1
```

A bit lenghty, but it will also work if you use `N4` or `N2` while you can have "m=3".

---

If one has O365, you can use:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A1:E2,I3,SEQUENCE(I1,,MATCH(I2,A3:E3,0)-I1+1)))/I1
```

That's made on the assumption you will always have "m" values available.

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:E2*(ROW(A1:E2)=H3)*(COLUMN(A1:E2)<=MATCH(H2,A3:E3,0))*(COLUMN(A1:E2)>(MATCH(H2,A3:E3,0)-H1)))/H1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I propose alternate solution (supposing that first column is A)

dataset

[image]

Function used for result

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT(CHAR(MATCH($H$2,$A$4:$E$4,0)+65-$H$3)&ROW()&":"&CHAR(MATCH($H$2,$A$4:$E$4,0)+64)&ROW()))
```

Check this for diff N and m

[image]

OR

[image]

If your data doesn't start with A always you have to tweak the values for CHAR() i.e. 64 and 64+1=65 only.